# how to speed up forming new column by multiple rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am about to measure the past few month sales situation of car dealers,

I need to calculate the average & sum of last 6&12 month,

The way I do this in python is by the following codes.

The problem is it takes forever to process when data is relatively large, when data is small it works just fine.

Is there any genius way to speed it up?

```
def ts(x,y):

    d[x+'sum12']=0
    d[x+'sum6']=0
    d[x+'year_flag']=0
    d[x+'sum_last12']=0
    d[x+'sum_last6']=0

    for i in range(0,len(d)):
        d.iloc[i][x+'sum6']=d.loc[(d.iloc[i]['PERIOD_ID']>=d['PERIOD_ID'])&\
                             (d['PERIOD_ID']>=d.iloc[i]['last6'])\
                             &(d.iloc[i]['RTL_DLR_ID']==d['RTL_DLR_ID'])]    [y].sum()
        d.iloc[i][x+'sum12']=d.loc[(d.iloc[i]['PERIOD_ID']>=d['PERIOD_ID'])&\
                             (d['PERIOD_ID']>=d.iloc[i]['last12'])\
                             &(d.iloc[i]['RTL_DLR_ID']==d['RTL_DLR_ID'])][y].sum()
        d.iloc[i][x+'sum_last6']=d.loc[(d['PERIOD_ID']>=(d.iloc[i]['last6']-100))&\
                             (d.iloc[i]['last12']>=d['PERIOD_ID'])\
                             &(d.iloc[i]['RTL_DLR_ID']==d['RTL_DLR_ID'])][y].sum()

        d.iloc[i][x+'sum_last12']=d.loc[(d['PERIOD_ID']>=(d.iloc[i]['PERIOD_ID']-100))&\
                             (d.iloc[i]['last12']>=d['PERIOD_ID'])\
                             &(d.iloc[i]['RTL_DLR_ID']==d['RTL_DLR_ID'])][y].sum()`enter code here`
        d.iloc[i][x+'year_flag']=d.iloc[i]['MTD_SAL_VOL_MKR_NUM']-d.loc[(d.iloc[i]['last12']==d['PERIOD_ID'])&\
                                                     (d.iloc[i]['RTL_DLR_ID']==d['RTL_DLR_ID'])][y].sum()
```

Comment: Hi @zhangwei da, can you add some sample data. I think this can be sped up significantly using basic Pandas functions like DataFrame.sum and DataFrame.mean but cannot figure it out without some data.

Comment: You'll want to use groupby and rolling for this.  No sample data means no way to show you exactly how.

Comment: Thanks! I will upload later when back to the office~

Comment: I cut a slice of this data,  dealer_id(RTL_DLR_ID) and period_id are the key connecting variables,     
              https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofr9maehyve2ppy/sample3391.xlsx?dl=0